# Indexing arrays with multiple conditions in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, indexing

Is there a simple way to access the contents of an array with multiple conditions?

For example, lets say

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But I'm only interested in values ranging from 2 to 9 (inclusive)

So I want to know two things:

1) The number of elements that satisfy these conditions (that is, where a>1 and a<10), so in this example it would be 8.

2) A new array with the values that satify those conditions. In this case,

```
new_a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I still suck at indexing in Python :/

Comment: Use a list comprehension.

Comment: you can provide your own function to the sort method in order to compare 2 elements, default is `cmp`.

Comment: @PauloScardine What does this have to do with sortingz?

Comment: @Barmar I misread the question as sorting with multiple conditions when it is really just about filtering.

Comment: Sorry, I probably could have worded that better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> new_a = [x for x in a if x > 1 and x < 10]
>>> print new_a
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print len(new_a)
8
```

Comment: I originally answered the question teaching about slicing as well, but OP isn't actually worried about indexes so this answer is correct.

Comment: You can simplify the condition to `1 < x < 10`

Comment: I like this one a lot! Didnt even know you could use if and for's in brackets like that. Thanks.

Comment: @JaronThatcher: Well, now that I see that, my answer is useless.

Comment: @JohnAlperto That's called [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and is one of the best parts of Python :)

Answer (score 2):

The built in filter function was built for just that.

```
def filter_fun(x):
        return 1<x<10
a = range(10)
new_a = filter(filter_fun, a)
print a
print new_a
print len(new_a)
```

## Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8
```

Comment: i prefer this answer, uses an inbuilt function

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is tagged as `numpy` and `array`, how about this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

In [3]: a[(a>1) & (a<10)]
Out[3]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: What the heck. I knew you could do that in MATLAB but not in Python. Awesome. I'd upvote if I could. Edit: Wait, I can :)

Answer (score 0):

For some arbitrary indices, you can use `itemgetter` to build a function

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> interesting_things = itemgetter(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> interesting_things(a)
('c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')
```

otherwise you can write an actual function for extra flexibility

```
>>> def interesting_things(L):
...     return [item for i, item in enumerate(L) if 1 < i < 10]
... 
>>> interesting_things(a)
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Regardless, you should put the logic into a function so it's easy to test and change